# 10+ Minute Gnome Desktop Load Times Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, nvidia

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 with a separate home partition.  After a kernel update yesterday (Friday, Jan. 8 2020), After the login screen I have to wait over 10 minutes for my desktop to load.

```
Machine :  Acer Aspire 5 (A5 515-55g).
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
Memory  : 7923MB (5740MB used)
Resolution  : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : GeForce MX350/PCIe/SSE2 (Nvidia driver 455 open-source)
Gnome-shell version: 3.36.8
```

**Solutions that I have tried:**

1. Completely removed nvidia drivers and used open-source drivers  (same problem, currently using 450 driver)
2. Booted from LiveUSB and ran `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX` on root partition, fixed all errors (minor)
3. Completely reinstalled gnome desktop `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
4. Disabled all startup apps
5. Updated to 5.9 kernel (current)
6. Tried all available earlier kernels
7. Booted to LiveUSB and ran Boot-Replair
8. Verified that all UUID #s are correct.

**EXTREMELY ODD**
When I tried to boot into `recovery mode` to run fsck I go the following message:

```
/libg/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.34
/dev/nvme0n1p5 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continure, aborting.

Finished, please press ENTER
```

This `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, outputs

[image]

`$ systemd-analyze blame`, outputs:

```
6.328s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
4.455s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
2.616s dev-nvme0n1p5.device                                                                     
2.293s mysql.service                                                                            
1.667s snapd.service                                                                            
1.548s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                                                     
1.522s snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount                                                             
1.505s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount                                           
1.423s snap-pdftk-9.mount                                                                       
1.417s snap-wordpress\x2ddesktop-109.mount                                                      
1.332s snap-pdfmixtool-793.mount                                                                
1.257s snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                                             
1.211s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount                           
1.155s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                                  
1.139s snap-snapd-10707.mount                                                                   
1.001s snap-core-10577.mount                                                                    
 952ms snap-snapd-10492.mount                                                                   
 895ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount                                                   
 850ms snap-kdenlive-24.mount                                                                   
 849ms snap-pdfmixtool-785.mount                                                                
 842ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2315.mount                                                      
 834ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                                                   
 726ms tlp.service                                                                              
 721ms dev-loop3.device                                                                         
 674ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                                  
 634ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 597ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b659bc0b\x2d8105\x2d4e5f\x2d8402\x2d89208c74620c.service
 564ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                                   
 520ms snap-ffmpeg-1286.mount                                                                   
 480ms snap-atom-265.mount                                                                      
 457ms vboxdrv.service                                                                          
 451ms phpsessionclean.service                                                                  
 411ms snap-core18-1880.mount                                                                   
 409ms snap-core20-904.mount                                                                    
 402ms dev-loop17.device                                                                        
 401ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                                  
 387ms dev-loop1.device                                                                         
 386ms dev-loop2.device                                                                         
 335ms dev-loop8.device                                                                         
 333ms dev-loop0.device                                                                         
 321ms snap-core18-1944.mount                                                                   
 306ms dev-loop4.device                                                                         
 273ms fwupd.service                                                                            
 256ms udisks2.service                                                                          
 245ms snap-core-10583.mount                                                                    
 234ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 230ms dev-loop5.device                                                                         
 225ms snap-chromium-1444.mount                                                                 
 225ms dev-loop6.device                                                                         
 224ms snap-chromium-1424.mount                                                                 
 220ms dev-loop9.device                                                                         
 217ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
 214ms dev-loop20.device                                                                        
 210ms dev-loop19.device                                                                        
 199ms apport-autoreport.service                                                                
 187ms snap-bitcoin\x2dcore-81.mount                                                            
 183ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
 179ms user@1000.service                                                                        
 164ms apache2.service                                                                          
 160ms dev-loop24.device                                                                        
 153ms ufw.service                                                                              
 149ms dev-loop22.device                                                                        
 137ms dev-loop25.device                                                                        
 134ms dev-loop14.device                                                                        
 130ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
 121ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 117ms dev-loop7.device                                                                         
 114ms bluetooth.service                                                                        
 113ms dev-loop18.device                                                                        
 112ms dev-loop21.device                                                                        
 110ms swapfile.swap                                                                            
 110ms dev-loop10.device                                                                        
 107ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 105ms apparmor.service                                                                         
 103ms polkit.service                                                                           
 101ms upower.service                                                                           
 101ms blueman-mechanism.service                                                                
  97ms dev-loop26.device                                                                        
  97ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
  96ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
  96ms dev-loop23.device                                                                        
  94ms dev-loop15.device                                                                        
  94ms dev-loop13.device                                                                        
  92ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
  90ms user@125.service                                                                         
  87ms switcheroo-control.service                                                               
  86ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
  84ms home.mount                                                                               
  83ms thermald.service                                                                         
  77ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
  76ms smbd.service                                                                             
  75ms nmbd.service                                                                             
  75ms systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
  70ms apport.service                                                                           
  63ms grub-common.service                                                                      
  62ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
  62ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
  53ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
  47ms dev-loop11.device                                                                        
  44ms secureboot-db.service                                                                    
  43ms geoclue.service                                                                          
  41ms lm-sensors.service                                                                       
  40ms rsyslog.service                                                                          
  40ms ssh.service                                                                              
  38ms winbind.service                                                                          
  37ms dev-loop16.device                                                                        
  35ms dictd.service                                                                            
  35ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1C0E\x2d0739.service                                    
  33ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
  32ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
  30ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
  30ms snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
  30ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
  28ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
  26ms hddtemp.service                                                                          
  26ms bolt.service                                                                             
  25ms dev-loop27.device                                                                        
  24ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
  23ms dev-loop12.device                                                                        
  22ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service                                                         
  22ms gdm.service                                                                              
  21ms openvpn@hktcp.service                                                                    
  20ms binfmt-support.service                                                                   
  19ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                                              
  18ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
  17ms openvpn@ustcp.service                                                                    
  17ms pppd-dns.service
```

user@machine:~$ sudo lsblk -f

```
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/atom/265
loop1       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/bitcoin-core/81
loop2       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/chromium/1424
loop3       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/chromium/1444
loop4       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core/10583
loop5       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core18/1880
loop6       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core18/1944
loop7       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop8       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core20/904
loop9       squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/ffmpeg/1286
loop10      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop11      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop12      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/kdenlive/24
loop13      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop14      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/pdfmixtool/785
loop15      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/telegram-desktop/2315
loop16      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop17      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core/10577
loop18      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snapd/10492
loop19      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop20      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snapd/10707
loop21      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
loop22      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snap-store/518
loop23      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/pdfmixtool/793
loop24      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/pdftk/9
loop25      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/wordpress-desktop/109
loop26      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop27      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snap-store/467
loop28      squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
sda                                                                               
├─sda1      ntfs     Data     6AC011DCC011AEF7                                    
└─sda2      ext4     home     b659bc0b-8105-4e5f-8402-89208c74620c     96G    83% /home
nvme0n1                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     ESP      1C0E-0739                              36.3M    62% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                       
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     Acer     FA780E9E780E5A31                                    
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     Recovery 12380F1D380EFF89                                    
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4              17940c0e-24cc-4477-964c-251be29ba859     44G    47% /
└─nvme0n1p6 swap              5fc4b948-a7d5-454c-a0d8-7160f260d09f
```

Would like to *use* computer, rather than fix *computer*, any tips? thx

Answer (score 0):

The major symptom / problem of the post has been "solved" with a temporary fix because this symptom is actually part of a different problem that I post about here.

[Fresh Install Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome-Clock / Calendar Corruption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306388/fresh-install-ubuntu-20-04-gnome-clock-calendar-corruption)